# HIbernate Query Using AND,OR,NOT conditions

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, hql

my sql Table and Hibernae Pojo class same as `Message:`--> column `toList,fromList,deleteList`.

i'm preparing Query:only in toList and fromList not in deleteList;

```
Query:select mb from Message mb where mb.toList LIKE :searchKey OR mb.fromList LIKE :searchKey
```

and How to Write NOT in DeleteList condition.

Comment: @Taky  How to write Qurery using Not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [hibernate expression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) to all operands available in HQL.

In your case according to:

```
Query: only in toList and fromList not in deleteList;
```

this should works properly:

```
select mb from Message mb 
where mb.toList LIKE :searchKey 
AND mb.fromList LIKE :searchKey
AND NOT mb.deleteList LIKE :searchKey
```